# Doxygen breaks my code inside pre-tag

Tags: doxygen

If I have a part of comment code in `<pre>` block, Doxygen will broke it.
For example:

```
/*
 * Find biggest letter one can send by some amount of money
 * @param money how much money on has
 * @return weight of biggest letter on can send by that amount of money
 * <pre name="test">
 * biggestLetter($money) ~~~ $weight; 
 *                                   
 *   $money | $weight
 * ------------------- 
 *    10.00 | 2000
 *     3.40 |  500
 *     0.50 |    0
 * </pre>
 */
```

1. If there is odd number of `~~~` combinations, the document
   will not papper at all
2. if there is blank lines inside the block, it will forget the
   pre-block
3. the `------` -line will make the previous line as a header

I know all these problems comes from Markdown support.  But even
disabling the markdown support does not help problem 2.
And actually I do not want to disable markdown support.

So how to tell Doxygen not to touch my code inside `<pre>` block,
so outputting it to document exactly how I have written it?

Comment: Would \verbatim be something for you?

Comment: Seems that `@verbatim/@endverbatim` and `@code/@endcode` helps.
Both has the drawback that then the `<pre>` is visible in document. And neither of them is known by Javadoc and one can not assume that everybody has a special docklet available.